# Only ½ logged in

Tags: bug, login

I have just logged in on a new browser. I am logged in here, but not here
https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or here https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/users/204/ctrl-alt-delor

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just click login? Do you have third-party cookies disabled in that new browser?

Comment: That worked. I logged into one of the others. And was logged in. But unexpectedly was logged in to them all (or at least the 3 that I tried). @rene I think you should convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: those other sites can share the cookie so you have no issues there. It only is a bit harder if you logon on StackOverflow, SuperUser, ServerFault etc as the thirdparty cookie trick is needed to work to be logged in everywhere.

Comment: I am confused, oh hold on let be check. Oh is it because the ones that end with stackexchange.com are treated as a group by the cookie policy.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290903/how-does-the-current-sso-of-se-work/309823#309823

Comment: I've logged in on stackexchange.com and had to re login on stackoverflow as well. Did think it was something about 3rd party cookies but still fails for me. Minor inconvenience